# rails mongoid find parent with child

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Fast Example,

```
class Band
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :albums
end

class Album
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  embedded_in :band
end
```

and the document will look like this,

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4d3ed089fb60ab534684b7e9"),
  "albums" : [
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("4d3ed089fb60ab534684b7e0"),
      "name" : "Violator",
    }
  ]
}
```

lets say, i want to make a method to find the `Band with albums name`

if this was `ActiveRecord`, it is simple

```
Album.find_by(name: "Violator").band
```

but what about like this situation?

Do i have to iterate the whole collection and find it like this?

```
Band.select {|band| band.albums.select{|album| album.name == "Violator"}}
```

Sounds crazy...

Or do i have to do the data modeling with `Referenced relations` not `Embedded relations`?

Comment: I'd say you have to get the bands with `Band.where("albums.name" => "Violator")` then iterate the filtered bands

Comment: but you are definitely seing the constraints of embedded stuff, push a bit more and you'll start to question nosql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embedded documents are best for items which don't need to query independently. If you need something to query independently, then consider using references. In your case, you can better find bands first by using specific album name and then process these bands

```
@bands = Band.where("albums.name" => "Violator")
@albums = @bands.collect{|band| band.albums.where(name: 'Violator') }.flatten
```

Here are more details on mongoid relations http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html